# Magento 2 Observer get product

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer

This is my code:

> magento/app/code/UV/Download/etc/frontend/**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add">
        <observer name="UV_Download_Before" instance="UV\Download\Observer\CartObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> magento/app/code/UV/Download/Observer/**CartObserver.php**

```
<?php
namespace UV\Download\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CartObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

    }
}
?>
```

This observer gets called when someone is clicking "Add to Cart".
My goal is to get the product which belongs to the "Add to Cart"-Button.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create events : `/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="productCustomprice" instance="UV\Download\Observer\CartObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create observer for that event : `magento/app/code/UV/Download/Observer/CartObserver.php`

```
<?php

namespace UV\Download\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $item = ($item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item);

        $product_sku = $item->getProduct()->getSku();
    }
}
```

In this observer you can get `Add to cart` product data. Please check it.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item'); $item is null. Edit: nevermind I made a mistake :)

Comment: It is still null. Your code doesn't work :/